# Oracle Express 18c log on from Java jdbc application

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

new Oracle Express user here,

I did the db install w/o problems in my Win 64 environment,
used sqlplus from terminal to create user and grant him roles and privileges,
and finally this user works fine with the local db from Oracle SQLcl utility -
tables, queries etc.

The problem comes when I try to use the provided boilerplate code from Oracle for Java.
In Eclipse, in new project, with added jdbc8 jars the tested in SQLcl user creadentials
are rejected with exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01045: user C##DBUSER lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied.

Here is the Oracle boiler code used, with my local details :

```
  OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
  ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1"); 
  ods.setUser("c##dbUser"); 
  ods.setPassword("dbUserPassowrd"); 
  Connection conn = ods.getConnection();

  PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT 'Hello World!' FROM dual");
  ResultSet rslt = stmt.executeQuery();
  while (rslt.next()) {
    System.out.println(rslt.getString(1));
  }
```

Would appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct connection string had to be: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE",
to account for the DB name where user was created and granted priviliges.

Answer (score 0):

As Oracle says:

> user C##DBUSER lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied.

Connect to the Oracle database as a privileged user (such as SYS) and

```
grant create session to c##dbuser;
```

(or whichever user name it really is).

Comment: it seems weird, this c##dbUser creates and drops tables; runs any queries from terminal - do I have to re-create the same account from the java code and grant him the roles/ privileges again?

Comment: No; if this is the same database, you can't create two (or more) users with the same username. Therefore, even if you tried, it would fail. But yes - that's weird. Are you connecting to the right database? You know, development vs. production?

Comment: It is the only one installed. From this boiler code I took the connection details - working fine also in SQL Developer tool.

Comment: Apparently, user exists. Otherwise, Oracle would complain about it first, not that it can't create session. Maybe your problem has something to do with Java itself; unfortunately, I don't know Java. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: Probably the problem is in the project settings. I tried first with the Oracle 18c (18.3) jdbc driver package, as the db version is 18c, but the latest 19c(19.3) also does not help. I used simple Java project ( no Maven or other package management ), and added jars by Project -> Builld Path -> Add External Archives.

Comment: I did say it was the only one installed, but you were right that I am not connecting correctly to the database - I took SQL connection details from here https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe/quickstart.html and they worked fine, but did not notice that Java details few lines below differ. Connecting from Eclipse/ Java I had to set SID as XE, not XEPDB1 as suggested. I came to it after querying the db name from my terminal - when I saw XE, then I found the same in SQL Developer and noticed how both suggestions differ.